# EF can't SaveChanges to db

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I try to create an `Equation` entity and to add it to SQL Server db, i do not get any errors in my code but i do not see any changes in the db.

I check the db in the server explorer in visual studio, and there are not added values. The db were added to the project when i was creating the ef data model for it in my project so the visual studio made a copy of the db in my project. But i don't know why it created two copies, in the project directory and /bind/Debug directory.

Entity Class:

```
public partial class Equation
    {
        public Equation()
        {
            this.Results = new HashSet<Result>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public double a { get; set; }
        public double b { get; set; }
        public double c { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

id is primary key and has identity(1,1)

My code:

```
private EquationDBEntities dbcontext = new EquationDBEntities();
Equation eq = new Equation()
{
    a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
};

dbcontext.Equations.Add(eq);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

DbContext:

```
public partial class EquationDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public EquationDBEntities()
        : base("name=EquationDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Equation> Equations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }
```

conectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EquationDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EquationDBModel.csdl|res://*/EquationDBModel.ssdl|res://*/EquationDBModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\EquationDB.mdf;
integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;
" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

App.Config of project with ef model(i reference it from my current project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EquationDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EquationDBModel.csdl|res://*/EquationDBModel.ssdl|res://*/EquationDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\EquationDB.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post your DbContext code?

Comment: Can you please show us your **connection string**?

Comment: Did you create each of theses attributes by yourself or are you using .EMDX model to generate it from the database?

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Can you please post some of your CONFIG file?

Comment: rodrigogq, yes i am using .EMDX model

Comment: Well, last thing I can guess i would change is to enclose your 1st line of dbcontext in a using declaration: `using(EquationDBEntities dbcontext = new EquationDBEntities()) { /*code here*/ }`, for you have to dispose the object after you use it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'not seeing changes in the db'? Where are you looking for the changes exactly? What happens if you try to read the `Equation` back out of the DbContext after saving it?

It's possible, if this is a Windows or Console app, that you're looking at the database file in your VS Solution Explorer but the file that's actually being used is in your bin\debug folder.

Comment: If your problem is what I think it is, this article has a good explanation of the issue (and the fix): http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx

Comment: Peter, i did as in article but now i get an error when i try to refresh data in the table from server explorer : "This database cannot be imported. It is either unsupported SQL Server Version or unsupported database compatibility"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because **|DataDirectory|** substitution string means that the database used by your application is located in the subfolder **BIN\DEBUG**. But when you add a database to your project it creates two copies,  one in project folder and another in **BIN\DEBUG**  and you expect that the changes will be made in database from the project folder that's why you don't see anything in server explorer, because it probably has a wrong connection.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the following in a try... Catch and set a breakpoint to see if there are any exceptions raised:

```
try
{
  dbcontext.Equations.Add(eq);
  dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Set a breakpoint and see if any problems are being raised
}
```

Comment: it doesn't enter in the catch block, no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your context (no pun intended) so try to set its state to added explicitly before calling `SaveChanges`

```
eq.EntityState = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

Although, if you have tracking enabled, it should know its been added.

Answer (score 0):

try opening the .mdf file from the bin/Debug folder and see if it has your data