# Have changes while debugging affect actual Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I've been trying to get myself into some EntityFramework lately.

My Problem now is pretty much the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677861/can-i-commit-changes-to-actual-database-while-debugging-c-sharp-in-visual-studio), but the solutions given there seem quite 'workaround' and dodgy.

I want changes saved to the database with `dbContext.SaveChanges()` to affect the actual database I created within the project and not one that is generated each time I run the Code.
Since I will use this in a project at work I'd like to know if there is a smoother, cleaner way than the ones proposed in the linked question.

I tried to change  `data source` in `app.config` from the original `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf` to the direct path (I guess that is not the way it works though).

Comment: Without knowing anything about how EF has been configured, there's not much to go on here.

Comment: If you want to use an actual database, then use an actual database.

Comment: Well I honestly just created a new Project, added an EF-Reference, made a new model, added database, generated Tables and added the code generating bits. So I don't really know what this configuration would be or where I would configure it. Would there be an option for what I am looking for in that?

Comment: @Amy , well I want the changes to affect the database file I added in the project.
I don't want to use one on an actual server for reasons of offline presentation and 'portability' of the the solution.

Comment: Weren't there different initialization options in EF? It has been a while since I used it. You had db.CreateIfNotExists, DropCreateIfModelChanges etc right? Is that gone? Sounds like your project is setup to DropCreateAlways of some sort.

Comment: @bastijn, I did not have to set/choose something like that. I'll look into the config file and documentation to find it.

Comment: @bastijn, what I found was the database initializer [link](http://tektutorialshub.com/database-initializer-in-entity-framework/).
Did you mean those? They unfortunatly did not solve my problem. My DB is already created but all VS seems to do when I run the code is to copy my DB to bin/debug/ and use changes only on the copied one.

Comment: @be_cracked yes meant those. Guess they probably only work when you use an actual (dev)db like SQLServer or sqlexpress. Not familiar with this copied db thing. GL

Comment: I got it!
I'll write an answer post.
Your help is appreciated tough @bastijn, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it almost right with editing the `app.config`.

You have to edit `attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf` to `Path\To\Project\Database.mdf`. Because `|DataDirectory|` will make the connectionString point towards `\bin\debug\Database.mdf`, which is a copy of the database you created in your Project. As pointed out by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256645/6585358).

Could have guessed that by myself I guess, but I'll blame it on me beeing tired.